# What elements of Renowned Explorers: International Society persist through multiple playthroughs?

Tags: renowned-explorers

I recently finished my first playthrough of Renowned Explorers: International Society, and since it appears to be a game that should be played multiple times and has increasingly more challenging expeditions, I have a feeling that it incorporates persistent bonuses that you get in one playthrough and improve the next playthroughs you do.

What elements, if any, persist from one playthrough to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dev here. Congrats on finishing the game, that's a feat! Renowned Explorers is indeed designed to be replayed as there is loads more content to see, and it definitely has a lot of challenges that are quite impossible to finish in your first playthrough (on Classic difficulty anyway). However there are no persistent upgrades so that anyone starting in the game has (almost) all the options and gameplay that a veteran player would have. The reason is that many players don't like gameplay being kept from them, or challenges watered down by persistant upgrades. As a player you will learn many things about the game's intricate systems so I'm sure you'll beat harder challenges in playthroughs to come. If you want to learn more about strategy in this game, feel welcome on the Steam Community hub to discuss or join in the Weekly Challenge.

The above being said, like Dulkan said, you will unlock characters as captains by taking them on a few expeditions. They don't make the game easier, but instead open up a few strategic modifiers. We're also working on an expansion, which will add more rewards for finishing playthroughs. These will be focused on increasing strategic and roleplaying options, rather than making things easier.

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: I didn't exactly mean "I finished my first playthrough". I meant that I just managed to finish a playthrough for the first time (not even winning the game, just finishing 5 expeditions). it also wasn't on classic, but on the easier difficulty. Kind of a bummer that there is no persistent element that can make it easier, though. I kinda love easier games, and I'm not really one to replay a game just to beat my high score or get a better ending.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I played (december) here were no persistent upgrades.

The only persistent element between playthroughs is unlocking characters as captains.